# Bootstrap 4 Grid - Repositioning of elements on window resize

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a very simple layout of 3 elements. I want them displayed on larger screens like the top layout in the picture and I want them laid out like the bottom layout on smaller screens.

I have no idea how to go about doing this. I don't know where to even start. I'm using Bootstrap 4, but I currently have it as a table.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="border:black"></td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td style="border:red"></td>
        </tr>        
        <tr>
          <td style="border:blue"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This isn't working markup, it's just to show the general layout that I have.

My problem is that on small screens, the content in the blue box gets so scrunched up it looks awful, so I want that blue box to pop out of the grid and display as a full row beneath the first two.

I know that there has to be a way of doing it with col-sm-* values and possibly order-sm-* but as I said, I don't even know where to begin!

Any advice?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this specifically using Bootstrap, but without Bootstrap you can Javascript to find the length of the body and use this to change your html code;

```
var widthSensorOutput = document.getElementById('widthSensor').clientWidth
if (widthSensorOutput < 600) {
    // Change HTML here
}
```

If you want to run this code constantly you can do the following in Javascript;

```
var widthSensorOutput = 0
setInterval(function senseConst () {
    if (widthSensorOutput = 0) {
        var widthSensorOutput = document.getElementById('widthSensor').clientWidth
    }
    if (widthSensorOutput < 600) {
        // Change HTML here
    }
}, 10);
```

All that "widthSensor" is is the following div at the bottom of the page.

```
<div id="widthSensor" style="width:100%;"></div>
```

I hope this helps. As I said, I have not done anything with bootstrap in about two years but I hope this vanilla Javascript solution helps.

Answer (score 0):

So, not wanting to use javascript to actually move the elements, I added some @media queries to change the font-size in the different sections to shrink the content so it's not so scrunched up and just left the layout structure as is.